# Eclipse does not format this if statement correctly

Tags: eclipse, autoformatting

This should be easy to answer:

I have Eclipse set to wrap Java code over 80 chars to respect my margin.

This code never wraps:

```
    if (expressionItem.type.isTypeCompatibleWith(containingNameLink.type) == false) {
      reportParsingError("expression type incompatible with containing "
          + "context.");
    }
```

Question: how do I set my code formatter preferences so that the margin is respected?

Answer (score 1):

Did you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (or right click > source > format) ? Here it works fine. The code is not automatically formatted as you type, you need to tell eclipse to format it.

Comment: I did, and it did not work. Eclipse version: Galileo 3.5.1; Build id: M20090917-0800.

Answer (score 0):

Click `Windows > Preferences`. Go to `Java > Editor > Save Action` Enable Perform the selected action on save then enable Formatt source code option.

Refer below pic:
[image]
Click on **Formatter** link to edit settings for Formatter.